# Facebook Session returning null behind ELB

Tags: php, facebook, session, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I am running two linux instances behind an ELB. My app has facebook login as a way of signing up. On the live environment, the user signs up from one instance, session is created for that but the redirection happens on the second instance a lot of times resulting in null session from facebook as that session is there on the first instance.

Help me fix this. This is very crucial to our product.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the most correct answer is that you should not design web applications without a proper session database that is accessible to all of the web application servers.

However, ELB provides a workaround for this oversight, known as "sticky sessions" (or "session affinity").

> By default, a load balancer routes each request independently to the application instance with the smallest load. However, you can use the sticky session feature (also known as session affinity) which enables the load balancer to bind a user's session to a specific application instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html

Of course, if an application server fails, or is taken offline for maintenance, your user still has an invalid session... but for the most part, this feature should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but sticky sessions work well with my regular PHP Session variables, for some reason they are not working with what Facebook sets in the session. My Sticky sessions are enabled and whole application works fine wherever the session data is needed, it is just this signup process that misses the data and returns null session. We don't have a lot of application servers right now therefore we don't need a separate database for sessions.

Comment: Help me understand what you are saying, here... you say sticky sessions in ELB is already enabled, and working, but you also say they aren't working ("the user signs up from one instance, session is created for that but the redirection happens on the second instance").  Can you expand on this?

Comment: Ok so the application uses session data in a lot of places and that data is available to any instance because of sticky sessions but FacebookRedirectLoginHelper doesnt get any session in this case. I think I will try to save session data on my own and not use Facebook's helper.